# Is Kotlin's runCatching..also equivalent to try..finally?

Tags: kotlin

I want to run cleanup code after a certain block of code completes, regardless of exceptions. This is not a closeable resource and I cannot use try-with-resources (or Kotlin's `use`).
In Java, I could do the following:

```java
try {
  // ... Run some code
} catch(Exception ex) {
  // ... Handle exception 
} finally {
  // ... Cleanup code
}
```

Is the following Kotlin code equivalent?

```kotlin
runCatching {
  // ... Run some code
}.also {
  // ... Cleanup code
}.onFailure {
  // ... Handle exception
}
```

Edit: added boilerplate exception handling - my concern is with ensuring the cleanup code runs, and maintainability.

Comment: The question is phrased as if Kotlin doesn't have a `try`…`catch`…`finally` structure very similar to Java's — but it does. Is there a reason why you don't want to use them?

Comment: Cleaner code. I wasn't sure if there are any special quirks I should bear in mind before assuming that the `.also {}` code is always executed.

Comment: I do the catch and rethrow very often and I find that `runCatching {..}.getOrElse { throw... }` pattern quite handful and very clean.

Comment: @KenIchi If you're catching and throwing the same exception it's the same behavior as no runCatching at all, how is it handful?

Comment: It should have been handy or helpful. (Sorry for my bad English ;) )

Comment: @m0skit0 No I'm throwing another exception (my custom one), so IMO this pattern is more concise.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

There is one important difference, where the code inside `runCatching` contains an early return. A `finally` block will be executed *even after a return*, whereas `also` has no such magic.

This code, when run, will print nothing:

```kotlin
fun test1()
    runCatching {
        return
    }.also {
        println("test1")
    }
}
```

This code, when run, will print "test2":

```kotlin
fun test2() {
    try {
        return
    } finally {
        println("test2")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

There is one big difference between both code samples. `try...finally` propagates exceptions while `runCatching().also()` catches/consumes them. To make it similar you would have to throw the result at the end:

```kotlin
runCatching {
  // ... Run some code
}.also {
  // ... Cleanup code
}.getOrThrow()
```

But still, it is not really 1:1 equivalent. It catches all exceptions just to rethrow them. For this reason, it is probably less performant than simple `try...finally`.

Also, I think this is less clear for the reader. `try...finally` is a standard way of dealing with exceptions. By using `runCatching()` just to immediately rethrow, you actually confuse people reading this code later.

Your question sounded a little like you believed Kotlin does not have `try...finally` and you need to search for alternatives. If this is the case, then of course Kotlin has `try...finally` and I think you should use it instead of `runCatching()`.

Comment: Thanks. I think I did not phrase my question accurately - I was mostly curious whether there are edge cases/quirks to consider in terms of ensuring the cleanup code is running.

Comment: Hmm, I personally don't see any such edge cases. I think we can be sure that the code in `also()` will be executed.

Comment: There is absolutely such an edge case, if the code inside `runCatching` contains an early return. A `finally` block will be executed _even after a return_, whereas `also` has no such magic. Here's a Kotlin playground link: https://pl.kotl.in/gbqwRNIcV

Comment: @Sam Ahh, good point!

Answer (score 4):

As per Kotlin's doc for `runCatching`:

> Calls the specified function block and returns its encapsulated result if invocation was successful, catching any Throwable exception that was thrown from the block function execution and encapsulating it as a failure.

Even if `finally` always runs after a `try` block and `also` always runs after a `runCatching`, they do not serve the same purpose.

`finally` doesn't receive any argument and cannot operate on the values of the `try` block, while `also` receives the [Result](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-result/) of the `runCatching` block.

TLDR; `.runCatching{}.also{}` is a more advanced `try{}finally{}`

Answer (score 3):

There is also a difference in what is the result of evaluating the expression.

Consider the following code:

```
fun main() {
    val foo = try { 
        throw Exception("try")
    } catch(e: Exception) {
        "catch"
    } finally {
        "finally"
    }

    val bar = runCatching{
        throw Exception("runCatching")
    }.also{
        "also"
    }.onFailure {
        "onFailure"
    }

    println(foo)
    println(bar)
}
```

The output will be:

```
catch
Failure(java.lang.Exception: runCatching)
```

https://pl.kotl.in/a0aByS5l1

EDIT:

An interesting article that points out some differences as well:

https://medium.com/@mattia23r/a-take-on-functional-error-handling-in-kotlin-515b67b4212b

> Now let’s give a second look at the implementation of runCatching in the gist above. What does it do? It catches everything.
>
> In this case, it goes even further: it catches all Throwables. For those not knowing, Throwable is everything that can go after a throw keyword; it has two descendants: Exceptions and Errors. We haven’t mentioned Errors so far; Errors usually represent something wrong that happened at a lower level than your business logic, something that can’t usually be recovered with a simple catch.

Comment: It's returning Failure because you are returning object returned by `onFailure`. If you use `getOrElse` you can make it return `onFailure` string.